# How to edit other user's name in a Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
    before_action :user_logged_in, only: [:edit ,:update, :destroy]
    before_action :check_admin, only: [:index]
    before_action :check_correct_user, only: [:edit ,:update] 


    def edit

    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    
    end


    def update
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_req)
    flash[:success]="Profile Updated"
    redirect_to users_path 
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
   end 


   private



   def user_req
        
params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
   end



    def check_admin
    
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    flash[:danger]="Only admin can see users"
    
  
    end

    def check_correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user and current_user.admin?
    end
```

## myindex

```
<%= provide(:title, "All users") %>
```

## List of all users

```
<ol>
   
<%= render @users %>

</ol>
```

## my user.html.erb

```
<%= link_to user.name, user %>

<% if current_user.admin? %>

<%= link_to "delete this user" ,user, method: :delete, data:{confirm:"Do you want to delete this?"} %>

<%= link_to "Update Profile",edit_user_path() %>


<%end%>
```

Comment: You have a check that prevents editing other users.

Comment: ```redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user and current_user.admin?``` 
this looks like you can only edit a profile if its yours and you are an admin. I guess the logic here might be to make this an OR statement:
```redirect_to(root_path) unless @user == current_user || current_user.admin?```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you have a check that prevents users from editing other users, specifically this part:

```rb
def check_correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user and current_user.admin?
end
```

So, as it stands, you can only edit your **own profile** if you are an **admin**. If you want users to be able to edit their own profile as well as allow admins to edit any profile then you should change your check to an OR statement:

```rb
@user == current_user || current_user.admin?
```

### Edit

Views

```rb
<%= link_to "Update Profile",edit_user_path(user) %>
```

Comment: But,it's pointing to current object  #<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"edit", "id"=>"10"} permitted: false> , This is the id i am getting while i clicked on update button,please check this

Comment: <%= link_to "Update Profile",edit_user_path() %>..also in user.html.erb..if we clicked update profile..to reach the id..what should be added in the edit_user_path( for getting the id of  clicked user)..

Comment: for your link you should pass the **user**, since that should be the object that you want to edit  ```<%= link_to "Update Profile",edit_user_path(user) %>```
btw are you using devise here? Im a little unfamiliar with your setup...

Comment: in the given solution.it's editing all the name,email,password.if i have to edit only name, what can be the solution,please check

Comment: i am not using devise here